# how to manage multiple form templates in fuelphp

Tags: php, forms, fuelphp

Hello I just migrated from CI to Fuel.... I am using Fieldset class to auto generate form in the view.... The problem i am facing is I have multiple types of form templates i.e some of my models use twitter bootstrap horizontal inline form where as few models use custom templates... I am able to set single type of form template in form.php which i copy from fuel/core/config/form.php to fuel/app/config/form.php

Here is the sample return array for form template

```
return array(
// regular form definitions
'prep_value'                 => true,
'auto_id'                    => true,
'auto_id_prefix'             => 'form_',
'form_method'                => 'post',
'form_template'              => "\n\t\t{open}\n\t\t<table>\n{fields}\n\t\t</table>\n\t\t{close}\n",
'fieldset_template'          => "\n\t\t<tr><td colspan=\"2\">{open}<table>\n{fields}</table></td></tr>\n\t\t{close}\n",
'field_template'             => "\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{label}{required}</td>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{field} <span>{description}</span> {error_msg}</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n",
'multi_field_template'       => "\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{group_label}{required}</td>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{fields}\n\t\t\t\t{field} {label}<br />\n{fields}<span>{description}</span>\t\t\t{error_msg}\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n",
'error_template'             => '<span>{error_msg}</span>',
'group_label'                => '<span>{label}</span>',
'required_mark'              => '*',
'inline_errors'              => false,
'error_class'                => null,
'label_class'                => null,

// tabular form definitions
'tabular_form_template'      => "<table>{fields}</table>\n",
'tabular_field_template'     => "{field}",
'tabular_row_template'       => "<tr>{fields}</tr>\n",
'tabular_row_field_template' => "\t\t\t<td>{label}{required}&nbsp;{field} {error_msg}</td>\n",
'tabular_delete_label'       => "Delete?",
```

);

I want multiple form templates like this so that i will be able to auto generate the form where it is needed using $fieldset->form()->build() function...

Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. try this:

> forge($name = 'default', $config = array());

```
$article_form = Fieldset::forge('article',array(
// regular form definitions
'prep_value'                 => true,
'auto_id'                    => true,
'auto_id_prefix'             => 'form_',
'form_method'                => 'post',
'form_template'              => "\n\t\t{open}\n\t\t<table>\n{fields}\n\t\t</table>\n\t\t{close}\n",
'fieldset_template'          => "\n\t\t<tr><td colspan=\"2\">{open}<table>\n{fields}</table></td></tr>\n\t\t{close}\n",
'field_template'             => "\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{label}{required}</td>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{field} <span>{description}</span> {error_msg}</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n",
'multi_field_template'       => "\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{group_label}{required}</td>\n\t\t\t<td class=\"{error_class}\">{fields}\n\t\t\t\t{field} {label}<br />\n{fields}<span>{description}</span>\t\t\t{error_msg}\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n",
'error_template'             => '<span>{error_msg}</span>',
'group_label'                => '<span>{label}</span>',
'required_mark'              => '*',
'inline_errors'              => false,
'error_class'                => null,
'label_class'                => null,

// tabular form definitions
'tabular_form_template'      => "<table>{fields}</table>\n",
'tabular_field_template'     => "{field}",
'tabular_row_template'       => "<tr>{fields}</tr>\n",
'tabular_row_field_template' => "\t\t\t<td>{label}{required}&nbsp;{field} {error_msg}</td>\n",
'tabular_delete_label'       => "Delete?",
));
```